# Homebrew error while installing any package on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, homebrew

While I am trying to install any package from homebrew, it returns me this weird error.

$ brew install postgres

```
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/github_api_headers20171005-1039-1blysiu
```

$ brew doctor

```
\Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_build.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_rules.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
  /usr/local/include/node/pthread-fixes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-experimental.h
 Error: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /tmp
```

Comment: Try the suggestions found in this GitHub issue of Linuxbrew: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/issues/224

Comment: The problem was that i lost permission to write to /tmp folder. This can [help you](https://superuser.com/questions/1133065/unable-to-write-to-tmp-osx-unable-to-correct-permissions-operation-not-permitt)